# apk terminal installation failed, recompiled as soon as decompiled

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I'm trying to modify a theme for android (cm11).

Since I failed to install the theme with my modifications, I tried to decompile it and recompile the apk without changing anything. The error that i have in return is always the same:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]

To be more specific:

- I downloaded a theme from xda
- decompiled on my pc with 'apktool d ...'
- recompiled it with 'apktool b ...'
- pushed it on device using adb

Comment: can u show your code wt u want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting security problem. Make sure you sign your application, and that your decompiled code do not have anything strange in it's manifest.